# Deleting data in database using wpf

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have got to make code to deletebutton - so if you select some data in datagrid you can click it and delete this data from database.

I tried it by converting data to my own class and passing to function 'delete' in my own sql class. Everything is okay about converting because I can print this class in function. But nothing more.

This is my delete function:

```
public void Delete(List<Student> listOfSelected)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=db-mssql;Initial Catalog=s18185;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        var tran = con.BeginTransaction();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Delete from apbd.Student where indexNumber=@Id"))
        {
            command.Connection = con;
            command.Transaction = tran;

            try
            {                   
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfSelected.Count; i++)
                { 
                    MessageBox.Show(""+ listOfSelected.ElementAt(i).index);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", listOfSelected.ElementAt(i).index);                        
                }

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                tran.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function is based on transaction and every time I tried it I can only delete one row. If I try more it gives exception.

Comment: Your loop is overwriting the the @Id parameter value, so only one element in the list will be deleted. You need to instead create and execute a command for each element.

Comment: I believe you can re-execute the command after changing the Id?

Comment: I`m rather new in that can you give me small explanations?

Comment: When you get an exception, you're only writing the stack trace. That will tell you where the code is that threw an exception, but it won't tell you *why* it threw an exception. Instead, you can just write the exception directly to the console, the .ToString() implementation will show the message and the stack trace.

Comment: So if  I understood correctly i should use command.ExecuteNonQuery(); in loop yes? But it doesn`t change anything. I knew that that was miss click and it didn`t help. It shows exception System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery ad it tells that connection wasn`t initiated

Comment: You may have other problems but you are adding the parameter on every loop iteration so after the first time, it is already there and cannot be added again. Declare the parameter outside the loop and just change the value within the loop.